# Show the agent name even not found?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to show `agent_call` in the result to include everything from `agent_call IN ('Agent1', 'Agent2', 'Agent3', 'Agent4')`

For example, the result only found `agent_call` Agent2 and Agent4 with relevant data and other none matching agent should be null.

```
SELECT monitoring_session.id, session_date, agent_call, Count(*)   AS total 
FROM   `monitoring_session` 
        JOIN monitoring_campaign  ON monitoring_campaign.id = monitoring_session.monitoring_campaign_id 
WHERE  agent_call IN ('Agent1', 'Agent2', 'Agent3', 'Agent4') 
GROUP  BY Date(session_date), agent_call
```

Comment: agent_call is in monitoring_session table?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad `agent_call` are in the `monitoring_session`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    monitoring_session.id, 
    session_date, 
    IF(agent_call IN ('Agent1', 'Agent2', 'Agent3', 'Agent4'), agent_call, NULL) AS agent_call, 
    Count(*)   AS total 
FROM   `monitoring_session` 
LEFT JOIN monitoring_campaign  ON monitoring_campaign.id = monitoring_session.monitoring_campaign_id
GROUP  BY Date(session_date), agent_call
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Only matching `agent_call` show up.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back did you remove your WHERE statement?

Comment: Yes I did. `agent_call` are in the `monitoring_session` table.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back i've updated `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. If it won't work then sorry for taking your time =|

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN if you want to get a result even if the join does not return anything.

Try this:

```
SELECT monitoring_session.id, session_date, agent_call, Count(*)   AS total 
FROM   `monitoring_session` 
        LEFT JOIN monitoring_campaign  ON monitoring_campaign.id = monitoring_session.monitoring_campaign_id 
WHERE  agent_call IN ('Agent1', 'Agent2', 'Agent3', 'Agent4') 
GROUP  BY Date(session_date), agent_call
```

Comment: I tried that `LEFT JOIN` did not work. `agent_call` are in the `monitoring_session`. Even no match found then still show it.

Comment: Please shows us your tables, otherwise it's quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

try this............

```
SELECT monitoring_session.id, session_date, agent_call , Count(*)   AS total 
FROM   `monitoring_session` 
LEFT JOIN monitoring_campaign  ON (monitoring_campaign.id = monitoring_session.monitoring_campaign_id AND agent_call IN ('Agent1', 'Agent2', 'Agent3', 'Agent4'))  
GROUP  BY Date(session_date), agent_call
```

Comment: Kinda working but I am getting a lot of different agents not included `agent_call IN ()`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back can give us the example